# Responsive - row of images, some having borders

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to figure out how best to make the 2 rows  of 4 images each on this page work responsively.

http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/index-real.html

Right now I have set each DIV within the row to width: 24%.  This would work fine if it weren't for the fact I need to have the borders appear on every other image.

Right now the image to the right of a bordered image ends up overlapping the border when the viewport gets smaller.

```html
<div class="instagram-container">
  <div class="insta-content">
  <div class="row01 inrow">
   <div><span><img src="_img/insta-01.png" /></span></div>
   <div><span class="frame-01"><img src="_img/insta-02.png" /></span></div>
   <div><span><img src="_img/insta-03.png" /></span></div>
   <div><span class="frame-02"><img src="_img/insta-04.png" /></span></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="row02 inrow">
   <div class="frame-03"><img src="_img/insta-05.png" /></div>
   <div><img src="_img/insta-06.png" /></div>
   <div class="frame-04"><img src="_img/insta-07.png" /></div>
   <div><img src="_img/insta-08.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

```css
.instagram-container {
 padding: 120px 20px 60px 20px;
 width: 99%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.insta-content {
 text-align: center;
}

.row01 div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 24%;
}
.row01 div span {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: take a look at box-sizing, then  float or flex :)

Answer (score 0):

They are overlapping because you are using `display:inline-block`. If you use `display:block;` and `float: left` then the overlap will go away (although you may have to adjust some of your other spacing). Typically then you would remove the `float` at a mobile breakpoint so each `div` is full width.

Comment: I've done that, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: It apperard to work wen edited through inspector on the live site. You may need to change the `display` on the `span` containing the frame.

Comment: Did that as well.. still has the overlapping issue though.

Comment: Ok, looks like the issue is that you were setting the size as a percentage, so  when the browser is too narrow, then then the `div` is 24% of the mobile size, so content is overflowing in an awkward way. You can see in the bottom row on the live site that they display properly. This would be an excellent case for using flexbox.